# catalina.properties gets overridden on Tomcat restart

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, catalina

I added a property to common.loader in Catalina.properties (eg. added C:/apps/conf) 
and it is getting reset when I restart Tomcat 7. Though this is not the case on every restart.

Wonder why it's getting overridden sometimes when the server is bounced, any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

If you're using Eclipse, make sure you update catalina.properties in the "Servers" project in your workspace before you restart.  This is the master version of this file and will overwrite anything you may have changed in your tomcat directory.

Comment: +1.  For reference, this is eluded to (but maybe not made as clear as we would've hoped) at http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ .  (See also:  http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/207068/)