# how to fix catalina.properties on accidental alteration of the code?

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat9

Its a hypothetical scenario.
I am working on spring-boot 3.8.4 . What is the best way to fix, if i unknowingly alter some portion of code of server file ,say : catalina.properties in Tomcat9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helpful reference - [catalina-properties-gets-overridden-on-tomcat-restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196982/catalina-properties-gets-overridden-on-tomcat-restart)

For such hypothetical scenario, always have a backup of original server installation. So, in case of accidental changes in server configurations, it can be reset by replacing altered part (or whole part when you are not sure what was changed exactly) with original (backup) one.